# clCreateCommandQueue fails with CL_INVALID_DEVICE

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu

I've successfully created an OpenCL context by calling `clCreateContextFromType`:

```
const cl_context_properties context_props[] = {
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)cl->platform,
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)interop_context->glx_context,
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties)interop_context->x11_display,
    0,
};

cl->context = clCreateContextFromType(context_props, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cl_error_cb, NULL, NULL);
if(!cl->context) {
    LOG_ERROR("Failed to create OpenCL context");
    free(cl);
    return NULL;
}
```

Then I've queried said context for the actual device via a call to `clGetContextInfo` with `CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES` parameter, and used the first (and, on my computer, only) device id listed in the result:

```
clGetContextInfo(cl->context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, num_devices * sizeof(cl_uint), cl_devices, NULL);
cl->device = cl_devices[0];
```

Yet, when I try to create a command queue via a call to `clCreateCommandQueue` it fails with `CL_INVALID_DEVICE` error:

```
cl_command_queue_properties props = CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;

cl_int error;
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(cl->context, cl->device, props, &error);
if(!queue) {
    LOG_ERROR("Failed to create CL command queue: %d", error);
    return NULL;
}
```

OpenCL documentation clearly states that `CL_INVALID_DEVICE` is returned "if device is not a valid device or is not associated with context".

The device id I pass to `clCreateCommandQueue` is the same id that was returned by `clGetContextInfo` call so it definitely should be valid for this context.

Why am I getting this error then? Is there anything wrong with my code?

I'm running this on Linux x86_64 with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 GPU and NVIDIA's proprietary driver version 375.26. `clinfo` runs fine and returns correct information about 1 OpenCL platform with 1 device (my GPU). I tried running some OpenCL code samples and they all worked.

Comment: Are you sure `cl_devices[0]` has a valid device? Or that the context was created with that device inside? clinfo lists all possible devices, but what the API creates when you restrict the context creation with flags, might be different.

Comment: Why use clGetContextInfo to get devices? You should follow what the samples that run do, and use clGetDeviceIDs.

Comment: FWIW (probably unrelated problem), I have a 2008 MacBook Pro with two GPU's (GeForce 9400M and GeForce 9600M GT) and I have to use the tool provided by https://gfx.io to switch to the GT card if I want to use it for OpenCL. If I don't perform the switch, then `clCreateCommandQueue` will fail with `CL_INVALID_VALUE`.  I only bring this up in case the GPU needs to be activated somehow... probably irrelevant... anyway...